# Nesting pages in the 'Manage Pages' view of Movable Type

Tags: nested, movabletype

On the `Manage Pages` screen in the admin area of Movable Type, is it possible to nest pages, or to achieve any kind of page hierarchy? Essentially I need to mirror the site structure.

I would also like to order pages, not by published date, but by a meaningful order - ie the order I need them to display on the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, create "Folders" in Movable Type and then place the pages into folders.

Be sure to place a page with the filename of `index` or an index template (or other template) in each folder so that when the folder is accessed without a file name, a page is displayed.

I'm hoping that MT gets rid of the "Folders" feature and simply have a parent-child relationship between pages in the future.